# Return a dictionary of words and their number of occurrence's found in a string

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp, counter

I have a large list of specific keywords I would like to count in a large string description. I would like to return a dictionary of the keywords and their number of occurrences in said string, for example:

```
description = "Apples and oranges are the best fruit, I'm growing some trees outside. Apples are my favorite, oranges are cool too"
keywords = ['apples', 'oranges', 'fruit', 'trees']
```

I'd like to count the number of times these keywords are found in the string and return something like this:

```
{'apples': 2, 'oranges' 2, 'fruit': 1, 'trees': 1}
```

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this, I've tried using Counter but was only able to figure out how to count the number of words in a list. Could I also use NLTK for this? I'm trying to think of a solution I could scale up for huge lists and descriptions. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this clear and concise dictionary comprehension using `str.count()`:

```
{word: description.lower().count(word) for word in keywords}
```